# How do I pkill a process and all its child processes by name?

Tags: process, kill

`pkill -f 'name'`  is not sufficient because it leaves some left-over processes in control group that ran while starting. is there any way to do this in 1 line or so?

Comment: https://www.systutorials.com/in-linux-how-to-kill-a-process-and-all-its-child-processes/

Comment: from that code where do i put the process name in it?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a method that uses pkill directly, but have managed to solve it quite neatly using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15139734). The key take away from that answer is you can use `-` before a process group ID to kill it.

Copying from them and making it complete using pgrep we get:

- `kill -- -$(ps -o pgid= $(pgrep -f 'name') | grep -o '[0-9]*')` (may not work if there are multiple matching processes)

You can change the `--` to `-TERM` (same thing) or for my use I used `-INT` to send an interrupt (Ctrl-C) instead:

- `kill -TERM -$(ps -o pgid= $(pgrep -f 'name') | grep -o '[0-9]*')` (same as above)
- `kill -INT -$(ps -o pgid= $(pgrep -f 'name') | grep -o '[0-9]*')`

During my investigations I found that PGID and PID were the same, and I found the following explanation from [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=shells-using-job-control-in):

> When only one command is entered, the PGID is the same as the PID. The PGID can be thought of as a systemwide identifier. If you enter more than one command at a time using a pipe, several processes, each with its own PID, are started. However, these processes all have the same PGID and shell job identifier. The PGID is the same as the PID of the first process in the pipe.

As such, in many cases you could forgo looking up the PGID. I managed to cobble together the following commands:

- `kill -INT -$(pgrep -f 'name')` (produces error if there is no process, only works on 1 process)
- `pgrep -f 'name' | head -n 1 | xargs printf -- '-%s\n' | xargs kill -SIGINT --` (does not produce errors if there is no process, works with multiple matches, though these may be children and thus cause an error)